# Why is the $_FILES variable empty when I POST to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, post, yii, upload

I'm following google's advice [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload). However, everytime I upload a file, a var_dump of the variable $_FILES returns an empty array.

I'm using the Yii Framework v1.1.14. I created a custom widget to generate a multipart form with a multiple file input, a javascript file to send the post data via XMLHTTPRequest, and a custom action to handle the POST.

Here is my HTML which is a php file rendered as a view for the widget. The url variable is the same as the variable passed into the widget:

```
<div id="gsfileupload" class="gsfileupload">
    <form id="gsfileupload-form" class="gsfileupload-form" action="<?php echo $url;?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="gsfileupload[]">Google Cloud Storage Upload (type:jpg, max-width:1500px)</label>
        <input type="file" class="gsfileupload-multiple" name="gsfileupload[]" multiple>
        <div id="gsfileupload-loader" class="gsfileupload-loader"></div>
        <input type="submit" class="gsfileupload-submit" name="gsfileupload-submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    <div id="gsfileupload-notification" class="gsfileupload-notification"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
/**
 * Google Storage File Uploader
 * Handles uploads via jQuery AJAX
 */
$('#gsfileupload-form').submit(function( event ) {
    // form element allows the submition of files
    var formElement = $(this)[0];
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", $('#gsfileupload-form').attr('action'));
    var fd = new FormData(formElement);
    request.send(fd);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(request.responseText);
    }

    // prevent the default action
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Here is a snippet of the PHP code for the file upload widget:

```
// Google Cloud Storage upload requirements
require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

/**
 * Initialize the Widget. Setup for uploading to Google Cloud Storage using 
 * a specific url.
 */
public function init()
{

    // set bucket and upload url for GS
    // uploads must begin within 10 min.
    $options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'my-bucket' ];
    $upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl($this->url,
        $options);
}
```

Here is a snippet of the php code for the action used to handle the upload:

```
public function run()
{
    // var_dump($_FILES) returns an empty array
    if ( !isset($_FILES['gsfileupload']) ) {
        // AJAX ERROR
        echo 'ERROR';
    }else {
        // move the files to the uploads folder
        for ( $i=0; $i<count($_FILES['gsfileupload']['tmp_name']); $i++) {
            $f_name = $_FILES['gsfileupload']['name'][$i];
            $gs_name = $_FILES['gsfileupload']['tmp_name'][$i];
            move_uploaded_file($f_name, 'gs://' . $this->bucket . '/' .
            $this->path_to_uploads . '/' . $f_name);
        }
        // AJAX SUCCESS
        echo 'SUCCESS';
    }

    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

If I remove the Google Storage API calls, I can get my widget to work on my local machine running apache. I've gone over google's documentation several times. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you set the form action to the $upload_url you receive from createUploadUrl(), which I suspect is the problem.  Your example form markup hardcodes "/manage/upload" in the form action, which is not how the process should work when uploading to appengine/GCS.

Your user POSTs their files to the generated URL retained in $upload_url, and then the upload service calls the url/handler specified in createUploadUrl() to allow your app to process the uploads (in your example code from the init function, this would be "/uploads").

Put another way, the subtle difference in the upload process in appengine is you're invoking a file uploader service.  The upload service receives the files and passes control back to your application with the appropriate $_FILES info populated, rather than having your app receive the files directly from the user POSTs.

Comment: Success! Thank you shollyman for pointing out what I missed and for clarifying how the whole process works.